# ConnectionRefusedError at / [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Tags: python, python-3.x, ajax, django, html5

Хочу отправить письмо на почту с данными из формы. Для этого создал такой код:

main1.html:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <div style="display: none;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="5">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.1.4">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="ru_RU">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f5-p2-o2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="2">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
                      <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" id="name" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Ваше имя">
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel-346">
                      <input type="tel" name="tel-346" value="" size="40" id="phone" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel form-control phone" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Телефон">
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="form-group-select">Как с вами связаться? (Выберите из списка)</p>
                    <p>
                      <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-586">
                        <select name="menu-586" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                          <option value="Звонок">Звонок</option>
                          <option value="SMS">SMS</option>
                          <option value="Telegram">Telegram</option>
                          <option value="WhatsApp">WhatsApp</option>
                          <option value="Viber">Viber</option>
                        </select>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-400"><input type="text" name="text-400" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text form-control" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Комментарий"></span>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="/privacy-policy" target="_blank">Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с условиями обработки данных</a></p>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap acceptance-608">
                        <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-acceptance">
                          <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="acceptance-608" value="1" aria-invalid="false">
                              <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Я прочитал и даю согласие на обработку персональных данных</span>
                              <div class="anim">
                              </div>
                            </label>
                          </span>
                        </span>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                      <input type="submit" value="Записаться на тренировку" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-chestnut" id="Ajax-form">
                      <!-- disabled="" -->
                      <span class="ajax-loader">
                      </span>
                    </p>
                    <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

form.js:

```
   document.read = function () {
  $("#Ajax-form").bind("click", function() {
    var data = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    phone: $("#phone").val()};
    $.ajax ({
      url: '',
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
    })
  })
}
```

views.py:

```
def send_email(request):
subject = request.POST.get('your-name', '')
message = request.POST.get('tel-346', '')
from_email = "ldr200@mail.ru"
print(subject)
print(request)
if subject and message and from_email:
    try:
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['ldr200@mail.ru'])
    except BadHeaderError:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')

else:
    # In reality we'd use a form class
    # to get proper validation errors.
    return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')


def hello_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return send_email(request)
    else:
        return render(request, 'hello_page/main1.html')
```

settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'v_*ls-2d4^xj-75-p2j56bw^ut=)8kh4a91pxop872nw%8n%g#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'maxsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'maxsite/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'maxsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

когда отправляю форму выдает ошибку:

```
"ConnectionRefusedError at / [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение"
```

Впервые с ней сталкиваюсь. В интернете про неё тоже толком не написано. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Настройки подключения к почтовому серверу покажите.

Comment: в плане, settings.py?

Comment: Да, соответствующие настройки из settings.

Comment: дело просто в том, что я даже не знал, что надо что-то менять в нем для этого.

Comment: добавил настройки в вопрос

Comment: В добавленных вами настройках нет ничего относящегося к отправке почты. Рекомендую прочитать руководство Django.

Comment: а можно ссылочку на статью, а то нашел только саму функцию

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/

Comment: я имел ввиду на конкретную статью. На доку у меня и так ссылка была...